# MQTT to Google Cloud PubSub republishing solution design approach / pattern

Tags: google-cloud-platform, design-patterns, architecture, mqtt, google-cloud-pubsub

##### Context

I am designing a solution where I need to ingest sensor data from different types of [constrained devices](https://www.netidee.at/comatrix/constrained-devices) into Google Cloud PubSub.

##### Pre-Conditions

- These constrained devices only MQTT and **only support MQTT over TCP**. **They do not support MQTT over TLS** and can not do any sort of certificate based connection.
- I do have the flexibility of picking the MQTT broker, however.

Given the context, pre-conditions, kindly suggest an approach where I can republish messages from MQTT to Google PubSub.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is more on the design and architecture, which is  not suitable for Stackoverflow. Please ask this question in [Software Engineering Stack Forum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all MQTT brokers support bridging to other brokers.

So the devices would connect to your broker using raw MQTT, it would then create a single TLS authenticated connection to the Google IoT Broker using MQTT over TLS and forward all messages over that connection.

This means there is no need for a separate client to connect to both brokers and forward the messages.

Comment: thanks for the response.
As a pre-condition, I have mentioned that the devices are not capable of TLS, they can only to TCP, which basically rules out he GCP MQTT bridge approach. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: The devices don't need to use TLS, they just connect to your broker as normal then the broker connects to Google the with MQTT over TLS (as I clearly said in the answer)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I am going to do a POC on this and see.

Comment: why do I have to use Google IoT core? And I already have a set of PubSub topics where I want these MQTT messages to be republished / redirected to. In your proposed approach, is that possible? I do not want Cloud IoT core to take over and use it's own topic structure.

Comment: I assumed you were using Google IoT because the link to the Google MQTT Bridge you provided explicitly talks about using it with Google IoT Core.

Comment: No, I am not using IoT core. I am editing the question.

Comment: It doesn't change the answer though, it just changes where you bridge to.